# Java threads and performance in parallelism

Tags: java, multithreading, cpu

I am working on a use-case where a monolithic java application (App1) fires some script to another DB application (App2 running in same machine) which runs tasks in parallel. While running the task it generates logs for every steps it is going through.
App1 needs to monitor the log file and understand which step is being executed.
The idea was to spawn a thread in  and keep reading the log file at certain interval, process the information and update it in a field in App1.
As tasks in App2 run in parallel and might need as many cores as possible, will spawning a thread in App1 affect the performance of App2.

Also, there is another use-case where multiple scripts be fired from App1 to App2 simultaneously. App2 will perform them parallel. For instance if 2 scripts are fired, 2 additional threads would be spawned in App1. This can increase to as many as 70 or more number of scripts. How much impact this can make on App2 as well as App1?
Could there be a better approach, handle the second use-case in single thread instead of multiple threads for processing logs corresponding to each script or any better solution?

Comment: Hello! In general, every thread doing work is taking some capacity away from the computer. Depending on the workload, the CPU or the IO operations tend to be the bottlenect. From your description, the App1's log monitoring thread is unlikely to take many resources away as it only does very light work. The App2's worker threads, on the other hand, will quickly drain the CPU or the IO (via DB communication), so sending only a few tasks might make all processing slow. The optimization of all this is a big question. From the system design down to low-level optimizations, there's lot to do.

Answer (score 2):

Spawning a thread and making it do something always has an impact on performance. How big an impact would always depend on the task you want it to do, frequency of doing so, its priority and obviously resources available. So to know the actual impact, you probably will have to test for. You may need to make the task less demanding ( decrease frequency of operation, decrease number of operations it needs to do, amout of data it processes etc. ), or you may find out the impact is negligible.

Disk operations tend to be slow though. Maybe making app2 inform app1 about the progress, instead of app1 checking the file by itself, thus not unnecessary performing another disk read operations, will produce better results.

As for the second case, again impact will be there. The actual severity of it depends on lot of factors, test for it. If it is too much, fixedThreadPool might help, or might not, depending on your app requirements.